# How to import submodule from a ts file

Tags: typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I want to import a submodule from a ts file into my project.
The problem is that the output file includes the entire imported file and not only the imported object.

I have an example.ts file with several exports:

```
export enum e1{a, b}
export enum e2{c, d}
export class exampleclass
{
    static f()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Update**:
I have another file - exampleUser.ts which imports parts from example.ts.

```
import {e2} from "./example";

export enum eu1{a, b}
export enum eu2{c, d}
```

I have a 3rd file - main.ts which imports parts from exampleUser.ts.
When I use the following import

```
import {eu2} from "./exampleUser";
```

and transpile the project (using webpack) the bundled output contains un-used parts of code from exampleUser.ts and from example.ts.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es3",   
       "module": "es6",
       "allowJs": true, 
       "checkJs": false,
       "sourceMap": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "strict": true,
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "strictNullChecks": true,
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
   "sideEffects": false
   "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
   },
}
```

webpack.prod.js:

```
{
   mode: 'production',
   module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
   },
   optimization: {
     minimize: true, // Control if the output is monified (and uglified) or not
     usedExports: true
  },
}
```

package-lock.json:

```
{
   "ts-loader": {
      "version": "4.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-loader/-/ts-loader-4.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-+zduqQJaeouVrGY3y6+nUG7+OE1+Q7slGCHsiQM/aITCEZ0og3GxrJVsnjM5QcWvOcu9C4VR5dP+egIyT+sNNg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "chalk": "2.4.1",
        "enhanced-resolve": "4.0.0",
        "loader-utils": "1.1.0",
        "micromatch": "3.1.10",
        "semver": "5.5.0"
      }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to import only the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you asking about is a  Tree shaking. Typescript does not do it out of the box. You use webpack which can do that. Please  see how to  set up it here [Tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

I guess it would be enough to set  `mode: 'production'` and webpack will optimize your output

UPD:

After some discuss it was found out: with typescript's target lower than "es2015" class will be compiled to regular function. Functions could have side effect via closures, so it could be unsafe to remove "unused code" and webpack includes everything "just in case"

To tell webpack that function is safe to delete compiler could put `#__PURE__` comment near the function but Typescript puts `@class` instead.

We can write simple webpack loader to replace `@class` to `#__PURE__`. It is a little dirty but workable solution.

```
module.exports = function(content) {
  return content.replace(/\/\*\* @class \*\//g, '\n /*#__PURE__*/ \n');
};
```

The [repo](https://github.com/yozi-developer/stackTypescript) with proposed loader

On my projects I prefer the following solution: typescript => ESNext javascript (ts-loader) => Es5 (babel-loader)
Typescript here is for type-checking, while babel take care about es5

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. I have updated my question with what I have found

Comment: ```https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#conclusion``` 
> Ensure no compilers transform your ES2015 module syntax into CommonJS modules

Tree shaking is a feature of Webpack and it can do it with `import/export` sources only

Comment: Are you sure your `ts-loader` or other loaders you use to compile typescript keeps module system as es2015?

Comment: I am no too familiar with the ```ts-loader``` and its options. I have added the ts-loader configuration in my code. How can I tell if it's changing the target code from es2015?

Comment: In my example, I see that the entire class (e.g. exampleclass) is included in the bundle (although it's not imported).

Comment: @ariel, Could you create a repository that reproduces your issue?  Like I did. https://github.com/yozi-developer/stackTypescript

Comment: You can check this repo, it works fine and does not include submodules

Comment: Once I've added the following code to exampleUser.ts ```export function euFunc()
{
    console.log(e2.c);
}```
The output (main.js) contained ```e.f=function(){return console.log("yozi"),1}}``` which is never used inside the file main.ts

Comment: Aha, I see. It is because of the following situation: with typescript's target lower than "es2015" class will be compiled to regular function. Functions could have side effect via closures, so it could be unsafe to remove "unused code" and webpack includes everything "just in case"

Comment: Then, near each class compiled to function should be a comment #__PURE__ which tells webpack "this function is pure and it is safe to apply optimisations here"

Comment: But 1) Typescript places here \@class instead of #__PURE__ 2) you have "removeComments: true" so typescript does not  place even \@class

Comment: I have found an article that describes this situation but it is on Russian, sorry. https://habr.com/ru/company/wrike/blog/342964/   Anyway, I updated my repo and it seems to work now

Comment: Thanks @Yozi, It works! The bundle (much smaller now) contains un-used static functions from imported classes. Is there a way to remove those un-used static functions?

Comment: @ariel classes are way more difficult to optimize than simple functions. I mean it is not easy to optimizers to ensure is it safe to delete a method or not. So I guess there is no simple solution